# MySQL server denies connections from local PHP script, but not from local MySQL client

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu, lamp

This issue has me a bit caught off guard. I've just set up this LAMP server and everything appears to be working well until I try running some of my PHP that communicates with the MySQL server.

Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 0

So obviously the MySQL server won't talk to PHP for some reason. I go ahead and connect to it with MySQL client, and have no issues whatsoever logging in and doing queries. I take a look at the systemctl for MySQL and find that it's purposely denying the connection for some reason.

```
vultr.guest systemd[1]: Started MySQL Community Server.
vultr.guest mysqld[17740]: warning: cannot open /etc/hosts.allow: Permission denied
vultr.guest mysqld[17740]: warning: cannot open /etc/hosts.deny: Permission denied
vultr.guest mysqld[17740]: refused connect from ::1
```

Right. So I check the hosts files and their permissions are set to 774, which realistically shouldn't pose any issue. I up the permission to 777 for sake of science and it doesn't seem to make any difference. At this point I'm somewhat at a standstill as I can't find any other leads as to what might be the issue. For the most part all of the configuration is default for PHP and MySQL at the moment, so I honestly can't think of any potential discrepancies arising from their configuration. Anyone willing to share their thoughts on this?

Comment: What is your PHP script's connection configuration?

Comment: What operating system you have ?? exactly ? can you show the output of ls -l /etc/hosts.*  also Do you have selinux enabled and in enforcing mode? What permission is on the /etc directory entry itself? Are there any messages logged in /var/log/messages relating to the problem?

Comment: This is just a standard installation of Ubuntu server 15.10. The hosts files are definitely all there and correct.          -rwxrwxr-- 1 root root  92 Feb 20  2014 /etc/host.conf
-rwxrwxr-- 1 root root  12 Mar  9 11:18 /etc/hostname
-rwxrwxr-- 1 root root 210 Nov 24 22:16 /etc/hosts
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   0 Mar  9 19:24 /etc/hosts.allow
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   0 Mar  9 19:24 /etc/hosts.deny        I never installed selinux, so that's a no unless it came by default in Ubuntu server. /etc is 774. /var/log/mysql/error.log reports nothing about this. This comment has horrible formatting, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

From your log it looks like the connection is made but rejected by mysqld, so this is probably neither a port-issue nor firewall-related.

As far as I know, If you use the command line client to make a connection to a server on localhost, the client always makes the connection through the socket file. PHP on the other hand probably uses TCP/IP.

Maybe there's an error (or some special security measure) in your mysqld configuration that has your mysqld listening on a port but rejects all TCP/IP connections.

Comment: I don't think this is the problem

Comment: I've double checked all the mysql config files in /etc/mysql and have not found anything that isn't entirely default. I am especially confused as to why the server is complaining that it doesn't have access to the hosts files, since they should be 100% accessible. As far as I can tell, it's denying the connection because it can't access the host rules as a sort of failsafe. But there shouldn't be any reason that it can't access them whatsoever.